# Javascript doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Javascript does not communicate with my HTML. I am trying to do a scrollto function but it seems like it is something wrong with the connection between my javascript and HTML.

**Javascript:**

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.href);
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 10000);
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="parallax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scrollto.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
        <title></title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" />
 </head>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you need to load your scrollto script at the end of the body tag, to make sure DOM is loaded. Otherwise you can wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //your code here
});
```

or use the sort version

```
$(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
  var target = $(this.href);
  if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 10000);
  }
});
```

You can replace body with any parent selector which are loaded in DOM.